# A problem comes when I add chinese,simplified to localization

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I want to add chinese, simplified to localization file and a message shows：
`“Localizable.strings” couldn’t be copied to “zh-Hans.lproj” because an item with the same name already exists. To save the file, either provide a different name, or move aside or delete the existing file, and try again.`

There is not chinese, simplified in the list and I just can't add it. By the way, other languages works fine when I try to add them.Anyone know how to deal with it?

[image: localization]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason at last. Maybe my colleague add the chinese, simplified before and he didn't delete the file in the project but just delete the cell in the list. After I delete the chinese, simplified file in the project, it works fine.